# How to specify which attribute to display in Select/Form in Laravel 4?

Tags: forms, select, laravel

I have a table called 'types' with the fields> id , name , ...

I want a select box to present ONLY the name attribute, so I do>

1- Get the info from the DataBase>

```
$types= Type::all();
```

and pass it to the view with a return statement.

```
return View::make('clients')-> with('types',$types);
```

2- I create the Select like this>

```
{{ Form::select('myTypes',$types) }}
```

But of course I am getting all the values from $types, not ONLY the name. Something like this for each line in the Select Box...:

```
{"id":1,"name":"name1", ....}
```

To solve it I tried this:

```
{{ Form::select('myTypes',$types->name) }}
```

but this generates me an error.

Any help is very welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you select, use the `lists` method.

```
$types= Type::all()->lists('name', 'id');
```

This returns an array properly formatted for select lists, key being the id, name being the value for each record you are returning.

Also, you can use the second parameter of `make()` to pass variables to your view instead of `with()`

```
return View::make('clients', array('types' => $types));
```

Then, the select list in your view...

```
{{ Form::select('myTypes',$types) }}
```

Comment: I also tried this:

    $types= Type::lists('name','id'); //Excluding the 'all'
then

    return View::make('clients')->with ('types',$types);

and the select form exactly as you posted, and it is working as well